# Did Disney make comics based on the books about Thrawn?

Tags: star-wars, comics

I’ve been rereading the *Star Wars: Thrawn* series by Timothy Zahn, and whenever I look up certain things, I’ve been finding lots of comic book like images with speech bubbles and everything. Are there any comic book(s) for the *Star Wars: Thrawn* series?

Comment: For the record, a canon is a body of works by an author. A cannon is a big metal thing that goes BOOOOOOM!

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Star-Wars-Thrawn/dp/1302911562

Comment: @NKCampbell - It's a bit more complicated than that

Comment: Given Valorum's answer, I took the canon bit out, as none of Zahn's original trilogy is canon. The more recent novels about Thrawn's backstory are canon, but Thrawn is a different character in *Star Wars: Rebels*

Comment: @Valorum, stupid autocorrect

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The canon 2017 novel *[Thrawn](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Thrawn_(novel))* (by Timothy Zahn) received [a graphics novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Thrawn)

[image]

It may also be of interest to you that the original (now Legends) [*Thrawn Trilogy*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Thrawn_Trilogy) books (also by Timothy Zahn) were [adapted into graphic novels](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Thrawn_Trilogy_(comics))

[image]

Comment: I was originally referring to the canon book, but it answers my question, and goes the extra kilometer